# JSoup parsing form with checkboxes and select input

Tags: java, checkbox, jsoup

I have a form which I have to read with jsoup, it contains several fields including checkboxes and comboboxes (select inputs).

I am reading there values with following code -

```
Element campaignForm = doc.getElementById("Campaign");
            Elements allInputFields = campaignForm.getElementsByTag("input");
            Elements allSelections = campaignForm.getElementsByTag("select");                               
            Map<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(Element selectField:allSelections){
                postData.put(selectField.attr("name"), selectField.attr("value"));
            }

            for(Element inputField:allInputFields){
                if(inputField.attr("type").equalsIgnoreCase("checkbox")){
                    postData.put(inputField.attr("name"), inputField.attr("checked").equalsIgnoreCase("checked")?"1":"0");
                }else{
                    postData.put(inputField.attr("name"), inputField.attr("value"));
                }
            }
```

So when I print the postData Map, it gives correct values for text input fields but for checkboxes and dropdown(comboboxes) it is not working. Please let me know if there is different way to handle checkboxes and select inputs in jsoup.

**EDIT:** 
Checkboxes I got working with help of comment, but select input still not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the checkboxes really have values? Legit question, because: `<input name="a" type="checked">` will generate a parameter (a=on) if it gets checked and submitted. So sometimes there is no need to work with values. I think the same applies for select options.

Comment: Is there any simple solution or I have to check all the checkboxes status for checked/unchecked and what do you mean by select options, coz they do have values? aren't they?

Comment: They don't need to have value attributes. The inner text will be used if there is no value attribute. Long story short on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewnmucck/) You cannot really run the example there but it should explain my comment (answer ;) ).
And yes, you have to check for checked attribute on the checkbox elements.

Comment: yes Meistermeier, I got checkboxes working but select input still not working :(

Comment: Just a guess: use #text() from the (selected) options in the select case. If you need a clearer answer you may provide some html you are parsing.

Comment: No I got it working, thanks Meistermeier for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working with following code -

```
for(Element selectField:allSelections){
                String nameField = selectField.attr("name");
                String valueField = "";
                Elements allOptions = selectField.getElementsByTag("option");
                for(Element opt:allOptions){
                    if(opt.attr("selected").equalsIgnoreCase("selected")){
                        valueField = opt.attr("value");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                postData.put(nameField, valueField);                    
            }

            for(Element inputField:allInputFields){
                if(inputField.attr("type").equalsIgnoreCase("checkbox")){
                    postData.put(inputField.attr("name"), inputField.attr("checked").equalsIgnoreCase("checked")?"1":"0");
                }else{
postData.put(inputField.attr("name"), inputField.attr("value"));
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use the value of the first option if none has the `selected` attribute.